# Optimal Organ Preservation in a Steampunk World?

Tags: biology, technology, steampunk, medical, species

In a steampunk world where multiple more-or-less humanoid species (with varying levels of intelligence) coexist, organ hunting is prevalent and authorized (outside of cities).
The harvested organs are sold for purposes such as transplantation.

What would be the best method to maximize the shelf life and condition of a heart using 19th-century-like technology?

Assuming a cold chamber, what is it that only allow us to to keep a heart viable for only 4 to 6 hours?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: They had refrigeration in the 19th century. The first ice-making machines were invented in the 1840s, and were widely used by the 1860s. In the 1880s ships routinely transported frozen mutton from New Zealand to England. (As a possibly interesting fact, [Carl von Linde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_von_Linde) invented his very efficient air liquefaction machine in the 1870s; the point being that they had cheap liquid nitrogen in the 19th century. His company, [Linde PLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linde_plc), is still in business.)

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please narrow down your question: storing an organ for consumption is different than storing it for a transplant or for taxidermy.

Comment: @L.Dutch Understood, thank you, I narrowed it down to transplantation.

Comment: @AlexP would a colder substance allow for longer shelf and viability of an organ stored within it for transplantation?

Comment: It's complicated, and requires actual medical knowledge which I do not have. But anyway, they had *liquid nitrogen*, available in quantity. How much colder do you want it?

Comment: You can't freeze human (or most animal) tissue without killing it.  Ice crystal formation will destroy the cells.  Low temperatures above zero will slow tissue metabolism, up to a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not possible**

Let's go through the background context for this question.  First, 19th century medicine is not going to enable organ transplantation.  There are a whole host of areas of expertise that 19th century medicine simply lacks, some of the most obvious being a lack of antibiotics to handle post-operative infection, a lack of immunosuppressants to prevent organ rejection and a lack of life support technology to keep a person alive while the heart and/or lungs are being transplanted.  (Note that it is often easier to transplant heart and lungs together rather than just the heart.)  While it may be tempting to hand-wave the issue and say "Oh, medicine is at late 20th/early 21st century levels even though everything is still relying on steam power," many of the developments rely on advances in materials technology and other fields.

Second, while the last decade has seen some developments in avoiding this limit, organ donation requires that the donor is alive and hooked up to life support machines at the time of removal of the organ/s.  The organ hunter cannot just shoot someone, then walk over to them and hack out the organ/s that are in demand.  They must capture them alive - or at least with oxygenated blood still circulating through their body - and get them onto a surgical table, hooked up to life support where a highly skilled *team* of surgeons will conduct the organ removal.  Several of the key organs, including the heart and lungs, require constant circulation of oxygenated blood to prevent their cells deteriorating.  Cooling - not freezing - and immersion in various substances after removing all of the donor's blood can reduce the rate of deterioration, but they still have only 4-6 hours to get the organ/s implanted into the recipient before they are no longer viable, as you noted.  (Freezing is bad, because it forms ice crystals that break cell walls, making the organ useless when defrosted.)  Without going further into the medical details than I am qualified to do, many of the reasons that organs have a limited lifespan outside of the body are the same reasons that suspended animation is not possible with today's technology.  There are very recent developments with the [Organ Care System](https://www.transmedics.com/ocs-hcp-heart/) as an alternative to the "traditional" cool storage of organs, but this is very definitely *not* steampunk technology and I cannot comment on how much it extends viable "out-of-body" time.

Frankly, if "harvesting" humanoids for their organs is somehow considered acceptable in your dystopian world and late 20th century medical technology is somehow available, the ruthless but effective thing to do is keep the donors brain-dead but on life support in a facility somewhere outside the city.  That way the organs are all in the body that they are perfectly suited to and can be maintained almost indefinitely as long as the iron lung and other support mechanisms continue operating.  Only remove the organs once a recipient is confirmed as being available and, preferably, on an operating table right next door to where the donor is.

Obviously, this answer is based on real-world human biology and technology.  I have avoided addressing the issues related to not-quite-human humanoids, though there have been attempts to transplant both unmodified and gene-edited organs and tissue from various animals into humans, with varying degrees of success.  Exploring cross-species transplantation in detail would require more information on the other humanoids from the OP and is definitely a separate question.

TL;DR - 19th century organ transplantation is not survivable.  Even if it was viable through selected inclusion of many 20th century developments, extending organ storage time outside of the body with 19th century or even 20th century technology is not plausible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the thorough response, it was highly informative, I definitly don't want to hand-wave such a major aspect in a story revolved around organ manipulation. I think my best bet would be to have transportable machines that keeps the carfully extracted heart fully oxygenated. I'll put more thought into it.

Comment: @Eyrm7 If you're not against some weird biology, a creature purposefully made to extract and keep organs alive inside of itself might be easier to create and explain than tech. Those harversters might also be the source of the chemicals you need to prevent infection and rejetion after transplantation. A biological source of those would help alleviate the need for progressing tech much further away than steampunk.